# Image upload using FileTransfer.Upload to ASP.NET REST API

Tags: cordova, asp.net-web-api, cordova-plugins, ionic-framework

I am currently trying to implement `Android App` using `Phonegap ionic framework`. My requirement is to upload an image from gallery to remote server. To achieve this I implemented `ASP.NET` `REST API` to upload image to server. (Let assume my URL to upload: `http://XXXX.net/api/Upload`). Inside my REST API I implemented `UploadController:WebController`. I has a Post() method which looks like below.

Server Code:

```
public string Post()
{
    HttpPostedFile MyFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["recFile"];
    if (MyFile == null)
        return null;
    return Utils.UploadToServer(file);
}
```

**My Android code looks like below:**

```
$scope.UploadPictureEx = function()
{
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="recFile";  
    options.fileName=$scope.emplyeedata.ImageURI.substr($scope.emplyeedata.ImageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";
    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.httpMethod = "POST";
    options.headers = {
            Connection: "close"
    };
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload($scope.emplyeedata.ImageURI, "http://XXXX.net/api/Upload/", win, fail, options);
}
```

Thats it. When I execute I always getting error saying `Error code = 3`. Can any one please let me know how to get this done? 
Is my approach of implementing Web API is correct? Am I doing some thing wrong? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled [cors](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) in your web api ?

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

and in your web api config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // New code
        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and in your controller you can fine-grain control what you want to enable:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // Controller methods not shown...
}
```